# sed or awk or grep to get first dynamic occurence of a string

Tags: grep, terminal

from this string

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/<name>.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
```

I want to get (and to print in shell) the first match after "...apache2.service;" 
This word can be "enabled" or "disabled"

How can I use grep or sed or awk to get it?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)... Are you actually trying to get the state of `systemd` unit ?

Comment: `systemctl is-enabled apache2` should print `enabled` or `disabled`.  Similarly, `systemctl is-active apache2` should print `active` or `inactive`.  Also, see similar use-case for `is-failed`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `awk`

```
 echo "Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/<name>.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)" | awk '{print $4}'
```

or `awk`

```
echo "Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/<name>.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)" | awk -v RS=" " '/service/{getline;print "",$0}' | tr -d ";"
```

or `cut`

```
echo "Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/<name>.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)" | cut -d';' -f 2
```

or `sed` to extract `disable` between two semi-colons

```
 echo "Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/<name>.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)" | sed 's/^[^;]*;//; s/;.*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **SED**:

```
echo "Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/<name>.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)" | sed -n 's/.*service; \([^;]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Using **Grep**:

```
echo "Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/<name>.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)" | grep -o -P '(?<=service; ).*(?=;)'
```

Using **AWK**:

```
echo "Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/<name>.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)" | awk -F 'service; |;' '{print $2}'
```

- will print the string between `service;` and `;`

Comment: thank you so much, for the examples and right way to check systemctl

Comment: @Lilia you could accept the answer if it works..